# find between places

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, mysqli, plsql

1. I Have a table tblroute_details

[image]

2. I want to find between places, I used that query

   ```
   SELECT (placeName) 
     FROM tblRouteDetails
    WHERE ID Between (
           SELECT  ID 
             FROM tblRouteDetails 
             WHERE placeName = 'Kaushambi' ) 
        AND (SELECT ID 
             FROM tblRouteDetails 
             WHERE placeName = 'Ghaziabad')
   ```

   ORDER BY ID

It gives error

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id, placeName FROM tblRouteDetails 
WHERE placeName in ('Kaushambi','Ghaziabad') 
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: it gives only top 1 records I want both records

Comment: what you need the places between 'Kaushambi' and 'Kaushambi'

Comment: I need all those places which I entered

Comment: having any specific condition

Comment: according to placeName which I entered

Comment: ok i enter placeName Kaushambi  and Ghaziabad
I want 
ID     PlaceName
9       Kaushambi  
10     Ghaziabad

28      Kaushambi 
29       Ghaziabad

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

The sub query `SELECT ID FROM tblRouteDetails WHERE placeName = 'Ghaziabad'`and `SELECT ID FROM tblRouteDetails WHERE placeName = 'Kaushambi'` will return more than one record.
Try

```
SELECT ( placename )
FROM   tblroutedetails
WHERE  id BETWEEN (SELECT id
                   FROM   tblroutedetails
                   WHERE  placename = 'Kaushambi'
                   LIMIT  1) AND 
                   (SELECT id
                   FROM   tblroutedetails
                   WHERE  placename = 'Ghaziabad'
                   LIMIT  1)
ORDER  BY id
```

> ok i enter placeName Kaushambi and Ghaziabad I want ID PlaceName 9
>   Kaushambi 10 Ghaziabad 28 Kaushambi 29 Ghaziabad

```
SELECT id, placeName FROM tblroutedetails
WHERE placeName RLIKE 'Kaushambi|Ghaziabad' 
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more than 1 rows with `placeName = 'Kaushambi'` and `placeName = 'Ghaziabad'` and this is why you get the error. 
Try with this:

```
SELECT placeName 
FROM tblRouteDetails 
WHERE ID Between 
  (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM tblRouteDetails WHERE placeName = 'Kaushambi') 
  AND 
  (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tblRouteDetails WHERE placeName = 'Ghaziabad') 
  AND placeName <> 'Kaushambi' AND placeName <> 'Ghaziabad'
ORDER BY ID
```